# Bind combobox items source to certain property of those objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Say I have have a list of TeamParameter objects that have a name and id property. I want to have a combobox that will show a list of TeamParameter objects but only display the name property of each one in the combobox to the user. Is there a way to bind to that property within the MainWindow.xaml?

Tried dot notation thinking it would work but no.

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        private List<TeamParameters> _teams;

        public class TeamParameters
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

        public List<TeamParameters> Teams
        {
            get { return _teams; }
            set { Set(ref _teams, value); }
        }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="LiveGameApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LiveGameApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">



    <DockPanel>
        <ComboBox  Name="TeamChoices" ItemsSource="{Binding Team.Name}"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30" Width="175" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></ComboBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Change your ItemSource binding to ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" and provide DisplayMemberPath property of the ComboBox as Name like DisplayMemvberPath="Name"

Comment: Thanks, its all good now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To point to a particular property on the data model you can specify the member path by setting the `DisplayMemberPath`:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

---

When you didn't provide a `DataTemplate` and didn't specify a `DisplayMemberPath` for the items of an `ItemsControl`, the control will display the item's `string` representation by default. This is done by invoking `Object.ToString()` on each item. Therefore as an alternative you can always override the `Object.ToString()` of the `TeamParameters` type (or the item model in general):

```
public class TeamParameters
{
  public override string ToString() => this.Name;

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" />
```

---

Or simply provide a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="TeamParameters">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I didn't think to override ToString() but that opens an intriguing option for me down the road. I went with the display member path option for now and all is good. Thanks!